# SAPUI5 Table cell valuestate disappear

Tags: sapui5

I am adding controls to SAPUI5 table column items via the controller using factory function so that I can apply cross-field validation along with standard control validations. Now the validation is working fine it shows the error message with the red coloured border, but when I move to next control, validation state of control disappear. I noticed that it is happening due to some internal functionality of SAPUI5 where it re-render the table body element of the table in the HTML dom explorer which also get rid of the error classes applied to control. It occurs for the first time, but when I try to change the value again of the same controller with an invalid data, it displays the error and keeps the value state with the red border.

my table XML view

```
<Table id="todosTable" growing="true"  items="{
                            path: 'TripService>/todos', factory: '.populateItems'
                        }">
                        <columns>
                            <Column id="id">
                                <Text text="Id"/>
                            </Column>
                            <Column id="title">
                                <Text text="Title"/>
                            </Column>
                            <Column id="url">
                                <Text text="Url"/>
                            </Column>
                            <Column id="thumbnailUrl">
                                <Text text="Thumbnail Url"/>
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                    </Table>
```

My Controller code to apply the columns item

```
function populateItems(sId: any, oContext: any) {
                const idInput = new Input({
                    value: "{TripService>id}",
                    id: `id_${sId}`,
                    liveChange: onIdChange.bind(this)
                });
                const titleInput = new Input({
                    value: "{TripService>title}",
                    id: `title_${sId}`,
                    liveChange: onTitleChange.bind(this)
                });
                const urlInput = new Input({
                    value: "{TripService>url}"
                });
                const tumbnailInput = new Input({
                    value: "{TripService>thumbnailUrl}"
                });

                var row = new ColumnListItem(sId, {
                    cells: [idInput, titleInput, urlInput, tumbnailInput]
                });
                return row;
            }

function onIdChange(oEvent: any) {
   oEvent.oSource.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
}
function onTitleChange(oEvent: any) {
   oEvent.oSource.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);

}
```

Some images with valid error state and then with buggy error state

[image]

[image]

As you can see in above two images the error is gone in second image though I expect it to be there.

Comment: Would it be possible for you, to build a working example of this issue in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ .
This might be helpful in debugging the problem.

Comment: I got it to work the issue is that whenever we change any value the table re-render the columns again and it loses all the value state. The fix is to store the generated columns reference and when table try to render the columns again I get them from the local stored reference

Comment: @AtulChaudhary Is the `TripService` an ODataModel?